# Enter panelGrid data from back bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:panelGrid columns="7">
   <h:outputText value="Name:" />
   <h:outputText value="Kobe Bryant" />
   <h:outputText value="Kobe Bryant" />

   <h:outputText value="Team:" />
   <h:outputText value="Los Angeles Lakers" />

   <h:outputText value="Position:" />
   <h:outputText value="Shooting Guard" />

   <h:outputText value="Number:" />
   <h:outputText value="24" />
 </p:panelGrid>
```

I have this table.
Let's say I have  list of strings.
how to enter this list to this panel grid from back bean.?

Comment: Looks like you may need to run through some jsf basics. Have you taken a look at [the JSF tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)?

Comment: Do all of your strings have to be in the panelGrid or do they have to be appended to Number: , Position: etc...